# Return last name Java method

Tags: java, return

I'm pretty new at java and came upon this challenge:

I have a method which reads a full name (doesn't have limit of number of names a person can have) and saves it in an array. This is what I have until now:

```
public static int readNames (String[] args) {

    int i=0, cont=0;

    String name[] = new String[99];

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {

        name[99] = in.nextLine();

        while(name[99].equalsIgnoreCase("END")) {

            name[99] = in.nextLine();

            cont++;

        }


    }

    return cont;
```

Now I need to create another method that receives by parameter a name saved in the array name[i] and returns the last name of the full name of it (sorry if I sound confusing!)

Something like:

```
public static (?) lastName (String[] name) {


}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you making an array of 100 strings, and only using one (invalid) slot of it?

Comment: I recommend improving `readNames` first, so it will actual work. Then you can solve other problems.

Comment: Thanks all for the help! If I include "return cont;" inside the for loop, the method will return cont?

Comment: @ccomann No, it will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on this line `name[100] = in.nextLine();` first.

Comment: Then how do I do to make the method return "cont"?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String lastName (String completeName) {
     String[] names = completeName.split("\\s+");
     return names[names.length -1];
}
```

And you would call it like this

```
lastName(name[16]);
```

What you are doing passing the last word in the string. This string is contained in the array "name".

Let's say you have {"Carl Louis", "Peter Griffin", "Mark Ruffalo"}

You call the method

```
lastName(name[1]);
```

and it will return "Griffin"

You need to be careful with the index you use. If you call lasName(name[99]) and you only have 3 names, you will get an exception.

Also your readNames method is not ok. You are always using 100 as index. Check that first.

Comment: Thanks! But if I want to choose, say, name[16] to be passed to lastName, will it actually return that chosen last name?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean then. Tell me an example. Let's say String[] name has {"Carl","Louis","Peter","Griffin"}
What do you want your method to do exactly? @ccomann

Comment: I want String[] name to have {"Carl Johnson Travis","Louis Gray","Peter Pitt","Griffin Von Fred"}, for example and I want my method to return the last names. Like "Travis", "Gray", "Pitt", or "Fred".        In this case, Carl's name will be name[0]. If lastName receives name[0], I want it to return "Travis"

Comment: I edited my answer so you get what you are asking for. HIH @ccomann

Answer (score 0):

you can try a better way by using `ArrayList`

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            ArrayList<String> fullName=new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> lastName=new ArrayList<String>();

                String name=in.nextLine();
                while(!name.equalsIgnoreCase("END")){
                    fullName.add(name);
                    name=in.nextLine();    // creating a list of full name

                }

            System.out.println("Last Name : "+getLastName(fullName));

      }
        public static ArrayList<String> getLastName (ArrayList<String> list) {

            ArrayList<String>lastName=new ArrayList<String>();

            for (String name : list) {
                String []n=name.split(" ");      
                lastName.add(n[n.length-1]);     // creating a list of last name
            }
            return lastName;
       }
```

output :

```
Carl Johnson Travis
Louis Gray
Peter Pitt
Griffin Von Fred
end
Full Name :[Carl Johnson Travis, Louis Gray, Peter Pitt, Griffin Von Fred]
Last Name : [Travis, Gray, Pitt, Fred]
```

Comment: Thanks!! But I need to save each full name entered by the user in an array with 100 slots! Meaning the using can only enter up to 100 names! And then I need to access the names the user entered in other methods! (I'm sorry if your code does that, I'm still learning programming!)

Comment: what do you mean by 100 slots?